# Which concepts of OOP are not available in PHP

Tags: php, oop, php-5.4

I searched this alot on net, but unable to find the answer that many people ask in the interview questions or in general question when they talk about PHP..

> Which concepts of OOP are not available in PHP?

I have heard and read this many many time that PHP is not a completely OOP language, 
but when i google it, i am unable to find that which concepts of OOP
are not available in PHP.

Comment: This one seems to a be a [good answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/78089/is-php-a-bad-object-oriented-language) to your question, what do you think? [Here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49842/php-structural-or-oop-based-language/50174#50174) is another one.

Comment: i think that this is not question for SO, but im interested in answer anyway

Comment: There are some problems I could identify so long I've been studying programming and PHP (about 6 months, I know, I'm a noob). Despite you can build a singleton class, it's based on workarounds and is usually a bad practice to do it. Another relevant point is that you can't cast a class to object instancing (ie `create((Book)$bookList);`). But I couldn't see any OO concept that can not be implemented in PHP.

Comment: This [answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/124252/193285) says you question is pointless. :(

Comment: @AlanMachado, try overload, make two methods with same name diferents arguments in the same class :P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in method for type casting of user defined objects in PHP (despite of having some workarounds).

```
<?php

class Book
{
    public $title;
    public $isbn;
}

class BookShelf
{
    public static function create($booklist)
    {
        echo "Here are your books!";
    }
}

$bookList = new Book;
BookShelf::create($bookList); // output "Here are your books!"

$bookList = new stdClass();
BookShelf::create((Book)$bookList); // output a parse error of undefined variable $bookList
```

Answer (score 2):

Something, which others languagues(strong typed generally) has is overloading, that means you can have two or more methods with same name but diferents args but PHP does not have it.

```
<?php

Class Foo{
    public function bar(){
        echo 'normal bar';
    }

    public function bar($arg){
        echo 'special bar with arg '. $arg;
    }
}

$f = new Foo();
```

You got this error: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Foo::bar() in`

Comment: So, [what is it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php), then? :P But anyway I've got your point... PHP isn't strong typed, so both of us are "correct" in the end. +1 for the good point

Answer (score 0):

1. function overloading
2. Operator overloading
3. Multiple Inheritance